# Linux regular expression command

Tags: linux

What command would you give to list all English-language words that are exactly 5 characters long and that begin with an upper or lower-case vowel (‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’, or ‘y’), have a lower-case ‘t’ in the middle position, and end with a lower-case ‘s’?

The remaining letters could be any character that occurs in English words, including but not limited to upper and lower-case alphabetics, numbers, hyphens, etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: grep ^[AaEeIiOoUuYy]t{5}.s$ /usr/share/dict/words

Comment: include any relevent code in your question, NOT in the comments. Makes it much easier for people to help you/

Answer (score 1):

You had it almost!

```
grep ^[AaEeIiOoUuYy].t.s$ /usr/share/dict/words
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I prefer complex pipelines to complex regular expressions, here's my take:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words \
    | grep -E -x ".{5}" \
    | grep '^[aeiouyAEIOUY]' \
    | grep '..t.s'
```

([Useless use of cat](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/) added for readability).

On my Ubuntu it produces this output:

```
Art's
Estes
Oates
Oct's
Yates
act's
altos
ant's
antes
antis
art's
autos
iotas
oat's
oaths
out's
```

(You can replace `.{5}` with `\w{5}` or with `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{5}` or whatever you like).

I've actually written a similar script to chea.. I mean, help me with crosswords.

Comment: how the lowercase t be in the middle

Comment: `grep '..t.s'` does the `t` in the middle and `s` at the end.